# Proton connection to azure iothub amqps endpoints

Tags: azure, amqp, qpid, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to use python 2.7 qpid proton (0.17.0) on Debian 4.8.4-1 on google cloud to connect to the **service** AMQPS 1.0 endpoints on an Azure IoT hub.

I'm using a shared access policy and a SAS token pair (which successfully work in ampq net lite under C#) for SASL PLAIN. For azure iothub, you reference the shared access policy as the username in the format *policyName@sas.root.IoTHubName*

When I use these (obfuscated) credentials with qpid proton as follows

```
import sys
from proton import Messenger, Message

base = "amqps://iothubowner@sas.root.HubName:SharedAccessSignature sr=HubName.azure-devices.net%2fmessages&sig=PERCENT_ENCODED_SIG&se=1493454429&st=1490861529&skn=iothubowner@HubName.azure-devices.net:5671"

entityName = "/messages/servicebound/feedback"

messenger = Messenger()
messenger.subscribe("%s%s" % ( base, entityName))
messenger.start()
```

I get the following error

> *(debug print of connection string being passed)* amqps://iothubowner@sas.root.HubName:SharedAccessSignature
>   sr=HubName.azure-devices.net%2fmessages&sig=PERCENT_ENCODED_SIG&se=1493454429&st=1490861529&skn=iothubowner@HubName.azure-devices.net:5671
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "readProton2.py", line 27,
>   in 
>       messenger.subscribe("%s%s" % ( base, entityName))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/proton/__init__.py", line 496, in
>   subscribe
>       self._check(pn_error_code(pn_messenger_error(self._mng)))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/proton/__init__.py", line 300, in
>   _check
>       raise exc("[%s]: %s" % (err, pn_error_text(pn_messenger_error(self._mng))))
>
> proton.MessengerException: [-2]: CONNECTION ERROR
>   (sas.root.HubName:SharedAccessSignature
>   sr=HubName.azure-devices.net%2fmessages&sig=PERCENT_ENCODED_SIG&se=1493454429&st=1490861529&skn=iothubowner@HubName.azure-devices.net:5671):
>   getaddrinfo(sas.root.HubName, SharedAccessSignature
>   sr=HubName.azure-devices.net%2fmessages&sig=PERCENT_ENCODED_SIG&se=1493454429&st=149086152
>   9&skn=iothubowner@HubName.azure-devices.net:5671): Servname not
>   supported for ai_socktype

The final error message looks like parsing of the connection string is being mangled (on a very quick look, pni_default_rewrite in qpid-proton/messenger.c appears to use the first occurrence of @ to split the connection string which could be the problem)

However, I'm new to AMQP and proton, so before I raise a bug, want to check whether others have successfully use proton to iothub, or if I've missed something??

Comment: Do you forget the double quotes of variable `base`, like this: base = "amqps://..." ?

Comment: No - they just got lost in writing the question

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow? Have you check [this](https://gist.github.com/tomconte/87c9fe34a166591c3000)? Note the address format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to encode amqp username and password.**

iothubowner@sas.root.HubName

```
iothubowner%40sas.root.HubName
```

SharedAccessSignature sr=HubName.azure-devices.net%2fmessages&sig=PERCENT_ENCODED_SIG&se=1493454429&st=1490861529&skn=iothubowner

```
SharedAccessSignature%20sr%3DHubName.azure-devices.net%252fmessages%26sig%3DPERCENT_ENCODED_SIG%26se%3D1493454429%26st%3D1490861529%26skn%3Diothubowner
```

The server name should be `HubName.azure-devices.net:5671`, but as you can see in error message, server name changed to `sas.root.HubName, SharedAccessSignature sr=HubName.azure-devices.net%2fmessages&sig=PERCENT_ENCODED_SIG&se=1493454429&st=149086152 9&skn=iothubowner@HubName.azure-devices.net:5671`

Comment: Does this hold for eventhubs as well? What is the method of encoding to use? Where is the MSFT documentation on this?

Comment: Thanks - eventually found a comment on this in someone else's experience of trying to do a similar thing